# How to update folder in SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, java-api

I wrote a java code to update(rename) a folder in SharePoint based on the reference in the link ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx)

Example, We are updating(renaming) a folder in SharePoint from 'Movies' to 'News'

The code get executed without Exception, but the folder didn't get updated in SharePoint.

The response returns with HTTP status code of **204(No Content)**

```
String url = "https://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/Movies')";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

post.setHeader("X-RequestForceAuthentication", "true");

post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
post.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
post.setHeader("IF-MATCH", "*");

StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'Name': 'News'}");
post.setEntity(stringEntity);
post.setHeader("X-RequestDigest","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
post.setHeader("Cookie",
"rtFa=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

if (response.getEntity() != null) {
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  result.append(line);
}
System.out.println("RESULT = " + result.toString());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The post.setHeader("X-RequestDigest","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");, did you hide the value or you are passing that value to the rest?